# UIButton's UILabel's background view does not adopt passed background color

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I am attempting to color a programmatically created UIButton:

```
    let button = UIButton( type: UIButtonType.System ) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake( 100, 100, 200, 50 )
    button.setTitleColor( MyColours.ORANGE, forState: .Normal )
    button.setTitle( "Some Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal )

    let backgroundColour =  UIColor.blueColor()
    button.backgroundColor = backgroundColour
    button.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = backgroundColour

    myView.addSubview( button )
```

But, as you can see from this image, the button's label has [what I'm assuming is] a background View of its own, that is not being colored. What I am doing wrong, please?

[image]

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. The button title label background colour is correctly set as blue. I am looking for the white border of the button only

Comment: Did you set any border for button?

Comment: Hi Balaji. I don't understand exactly what you mean, I'm afraid. For clarity: the whole blue rectangle area outside the white rounded-corner area is the button.

Comment: Oh.. ok i thought it was the view where u added the button

Comment: If you remove button.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = backgroundColour line form your code. Whats the result?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have taken system button and not custom button?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the button's border with
`button.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;`

Comment: Hi Martijn. I tried both `button.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;` and `button.titleLabel?.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;` but neither of which helped. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reordering the code has removed the problem, which is good, although I don't know how or why it works, which is less good:

```
    var backgroundColour = UIColor.BlueColor()
    var foregroundColour = MyColours.ORANGE
    var button = UIButton( type: UIButtonType.System ) as UIButton

    button.frame = CGRectMake( 100, 100, 200, 50 )
    button.backgroundColor = backgroundColour
    button.setTitleColor( foregroundColour, forState: .Normal )
    button.setTitle( "Some Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal )

    myView.addSubview( button )
```